# What is the probability of getting one of each 10 different figures if we bought 25 pack?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, coupon-collector

There are 10 differente figures (A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J), all equally probable to get.

We bought 25 pack which each contains only 1 figure

What is the porbability if we bought 25 packs we got all the differente figures, we found all the figures?

I figured that the total numbers of outcomes will be based on repetitive combination so (25-1+10 10) but i don't know how i should calculate the numbers of possible good outcomes

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Please show your efforts on the question to avoid it being closed or heavily downvoted. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?r=SearchResults) to know how to ask a good question on this website. (Please take note that this website does **not** do your homework for you)

Comment: well i figured out, that the sum of the outcomes will be based on repetitive combination so (25-1+10 10), but i can't get around my head that how i should calculate the number of ways this event can happen.

Comment: i don't understand is it given that we found all the figures after opening the packs? is it a conditional probability? what is the second sentence meant to be "we found all the figures?"

Comment: @OUR i just wanted to emphasis that we find all the 10 differente figures after opening all of the 25 packs, so it doesn't matter if we found 1 figure multiple times as long as we found at least one out of the remaining 9 - this was just an example

Comment: Have you read about the coupon collector's problem?  This is not the same, but the logic is useful.

Comment: If ${25-1+10\choose 10}$ corresponds to [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) method, you can assume that in good outcome each bar has a star 'glued' to it. Hope that helps.

Comment: @Alexey Burdin so you are saying that each bar has one star glued to it, which means 25 - 10 = 15, which means we have 15 figures left to place, so then (15−1+10 10) or am i wrong?

Comment: Seems right, but I'm not that sure, just wanted to point the approach if it makes sense.

Comment: I dont think stars & bars are applicable here.  That counts the number of ways to distribute 25 indistinguishable packs into 10 distinguishable figures, but not every such way is equi-probable if the underlying model is that each pack is equi-probable to be any of the 10.

Comment: @joriki:  only that it wants the probability of all coupons with a given number of draws, not the expected number of draws to get them all.  I didn't know about the one you link to.  I agree it is a duplicate

Comment: @RossMillikan: OK, thanks, I closed it. I collected the questions about the coupon collector problem that often come up as duplicates in [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29382) in the [List of Generalizations of Common Questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1868). (Does that make me a coupon collectors' collector? :-)

Comment: @joriki Since you closed my question and said it was a duplicate, i looked into the "Probability distribution in the coupon collector's problem" which you gave me, but i don't understand that how it connects to my problem? I see what you dod there but in the m∑j=1m1/j : how should i use this function with my problem?

Comment: @No_Name: That's hard to read; please use MathJax for formatting; [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)'s a tutorial and reference. I'm guessing that you're referring to the expected value at the end of the answer. I specifically linked to that question because it doesn't just give the well-known expected value, but the entire probaility distribution, which is what you'd asked about. I'm not sure why you're focussing on the expected value.

Comment: @joriki Well i found a formula online which is called poincare formula and using this formula my final result looks like this : $1-\sum_{i=1}^{10}(-1)^{i-1}*\binom{10}{i}*(\frac{10 - i}{10})^{25}$ . So is it wrong, or am i using it wrong?

Comment: @No_Name: Did you look at the linked answer?